# Python - Removing special characters and adding numbers from String

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

I have the below code. There is a string with special characters and numbers. I try to remove the special characters and calculate the sum of the numbers in the string. I get error when i try to convert string characters to integers . What am i missing here? Thank you!

```py
number="4009-0000-0060"
sum1=0
for char in number:
    number=number.replace("-","")
    sum1+=int(char)
print(sum1)
```

Comment: Just for fun, and hopefully to encourage a bit of personal research into various builtin Python functions; this is nice and efficient: `sum(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, number)))`.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```py
number=number.replace("-","")
```

I guess you wanted to use `char` instead of `number`:

```py
char = char.replace("-", "")
```

But even by doing so the code doesn't work when `char` gets the value of `'-'`:
`'-'` becomes empty string and empty string can't be converted to `int`.

You could replace it to `"0"` instead:

```py
char = char.replace("-", "0")
```

---

Another solution is to not remove characters from the string but only pick the integers like:

```py
number = "4009-0000-0060"
print(sum(int(char) for char in number if char.isdigit()))
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP intended `char = char.replace("-", "0")`.

Comment: @ekhumoro You're right. Added to the answer.

Comment: The Number variable that i loop through is a string, i have to convert characters to integers. It is not just the "-"

Comment: @DMach It doesn't matter what it is, as long as it's not a digit is will be skipped. All symbols are gonna get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

A solution near yours without `replace()` and not in list comprehension.

1. You check if it is digit
2. If yes, you add the character after being *converted* to integer
3. If no, the loop continues to the next character

```py
def main():
    number = "4009-0000-0060"
    sum1 = 0
    for char in number:
        if char.isdigit():
            sum1 += int(char)
            
    print(sum1)
```

Outputs `19`.

Comment: The Number variable that i loop through is a string, i have to convert characters to integers. It is not just the "-"

Comment: What do you mean? With my solution, you just check if it is digit, and if so, you sum it. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work

```
number="4009-0000-0060"
sum1=0
for char in number:
    char=char.replace("-","0")
    char=int(char)
    sum1+=char
print(sum1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to continue when the char is `-`

```
number = "4009-0000-0060"
sum1 = 0
for char in number:
    if char == '-':
        continue
    sum1 += int(char)
print(sum1)
```

Or matching all the digits 0-9 and then sum:

```
import re

number = "4009-0000-0060"
sum1 = sum(map(int, re.findall(r"[0-9]", number)))
print(sum1)
```

Both will output `19`